# Nagios: NRPE: Unable to read output, Can't find the reason, can you?

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I have a Nagios server and a monitored server.
On the monitored server:

```
[root@Monitored ~]# netstat -an |grep :5666
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5666                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
[root@Monitored ~]# locate check_kvm
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kvm
[root@Monitored ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kvm -H localhost
hosts:3 OK:3 WARN:0 CRIT:0 - ab2c7:running alpweb5:running istaweb5:running
[root@Monitored ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_kvm
NRPE: Unable to read output
[root@Monitored ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H localhost
NRPE v2.14
[root@Monitored ~]# ps -ef |grep nrpe
nagios   21178     1  0 16:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/nrpe -c /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg -d
[root@Monitored ~]#
```

On the Nagios server:

```
[root@Nagios ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 1.1.1.159 -c check_kvm
NRPE: Unable to read output
[root@Nagios ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 1.1.1.159
NRPE v2.14
[root@Nagios ~]#
```

When I check another server in the network using the same command it works:

```
[root@Nagios ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 1.1.1.80 -c check_kvm
hosts:4 OK:4 WARN:0 CRIT:0 - karmisoft:running ab2c4:running kidumim1:running travel2gether1:running
[root@Nagios ~]#
```

Running the check locally using Nagios account:

```
[root@Monitored ~]# su - nagios
-bash-4.1$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kvm
hosts:3 OK:3 WARN:0 CRIT:0 - ab2c7:running alpweb5:running istaweb5:running
-bash-4.1$
```

Running the check remotely from the Nagios server using Nagios account:

```
-bash-4.1$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 1.1.1.159 -c check_kvm
NRPE: Unable to read output
-bash-4.1$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 1.1.1.159
NRPE v2.14
-bash-4.1$
```

Running the same check_kvm against a different server in the network using Nagios account:

```
-bash-4.1$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 1.1.1.80 -c check_kvm
hosts:4 OK:4 WARN:0 CRIT:0 - karmisoft:running ab2c4:running kidumim1:running travel2gether1:running
-bash-4.1$
```

Permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4684 2013-10-14 17:14 nrpe.cfg (aka /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg)
drwxrwxr-x. 3 nagios nagios 4096 2013-10-15 03:38 plugins (aka /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins)
```

`/etc/sudoers:`

```
[root@Monitored ~]# grep -i requiretty /etc/sudoers
#Defaults    requiretty
```

iptables/selinux:

```
[root@Monitored xinetd.d]# service iptables status
iptables: Firewall is not running.
[root@Monitored xinetd.d]# service ip6tables status
ip6tables: Firewall is not running.
[root@Monitored xinetd.d]# grep disable /etc/selinux/config 
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
[root@Monitored xinetd.d]#
```

The command in `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` is:

```
[root@Monitored ~]# grep kvm /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg 
command[check_kvm]=sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kvm
```

and the `nagios` user is added on `/etc/sudoers`:

```
nagios  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kvm
nagios  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe
```

The `check_kvm` is a shell script, looks like that:

```
#!/bin/sh

LIST=$(virsh list --all | sed '1,2d' | sed '/^$/d'| awk '{print $2":"$3}')

if [ ! "$LIST" ]; then
  EXITVAL=3 #Status 3 = UNKNOWN (orange) 
  echo "Unknown guests"
  exit $EXITVAL
fi

OK=0
WARN=0
CRIT=0
NUM=0

for host in $(echo $LIST)
do
  name=$(echo $host | awk -F: '{print $1}')
  state=$(echo $host | awk -F: '{print $2}')
  NUM=$(expr $NUM + 1)

  case "$state" in
    running|blocked) OK=$(expr $OK + 1) ;;
    paused) WARN=$(expr $WARN + 1) ;;
    shutdown|shut*|crashed) CRIT=$(expr $CRIT + 1) ;;
    *) CRIT=$(expr $CRIT + 1) ;;
  esac
done

if [ "$NUM" -eq "$OK" ]; then
  EXITVAL=0 #Status 0 = OK (green)
fi

if [ "$WARN" -gt 0 ]; then
  EXITVAL=1 #Status 1 = WARNING (yellow)
fi

if [ "$CRIT" -gt 0 ]; then
  EXITVAL=2 #Status 2 = CRITICAL (red)
fi

echo hosts:$NUM OK:$OK WARN:$WARN CRIT:$CRIT - $LIST

exit $EXITVAL
```

Edit (10/22/13):
Following all that, I am now able to get some response from the script:

```
[root@Monitored ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_kvm
Unknown guests
[root@Monitored ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H localhost
NRPE v2.14
[root@Monitored ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kvm
hosts:3 OK:3 WARN:0 CRIT:0 - ab2c7:running alpweb5:running istaweb5:running
[root@Monitored ~]# su - nagios
-bash-4.1$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kvm
hosts:3 OK:3 WARN:0 CRIT:0 - ab2c7:running alpweb5:running istaweb5:running
-bash-4.1$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_kvm
Unknown guests
-bash-4.1$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H localhost
NRPE v2.14
```

It seems like the problem is some how related to the `check_nrpe` command or something which is related to the `nrpe` installation on the server.

Edit 12/2/13:
Other checks on the problematic server work:
[image]

Comment: What's the line in `nrpe.cfg` for that particular command on the client? What type of plugin is this (bash/perl/etc)?

Comment: I've edited my original question and added the information you asked for

Comment: Do other NRPE checks work on that host? And does NRPE log anything when that check fails?

Comment: Yes, as you can see on the attached photo, other checks does work, using both nrpe and snmp, only that check_kvm doesn't work.
I see nothing regarding the fail in the logs.
Since then I've installed a few more physical vm host servers and added them to be monitored by Nagios but I didn;t encounter the problem there and the check_kvm commands work on them perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice detailed write-up Itai! Have you tried reducing the complexity of the config to see if it works?

For starters, I would start by changing the line in `nrpe.cfg` to

```
command[check_kvm]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kvm
```

and temporarily change the /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kvm script to be something really simple like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Hi
exit 0
```

If that works, then you can start ratcheting up the complexity. Perhaps instead of giving the `nagios` user sudo access to the script, it really needs access to the `virsh` command and you can leave out the `sudo` part in the `nrpe.cfg` command line.

Comment: I Have tried it and still getting NRPE: Unable to read output, any more suggestions?

Comment: What are the ownership and permissions on `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kvm` ?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 nagios nagios 2581 2013-10-17 13:48 /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kvm`

Comment: Did you try changing the script itself to something simple? I don't think the basic "Hi" one I suggested would be 2581 bytes?

Comment: Yes, I've tried changing the script but to no avail.
more than that, the script works just fine when checked against another server, or if i run it locally, only when i use the `check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_kvm` method it returns `Unknown guests`

Comment: But `Unknown guests` is progress! Because that's a legitimate exit value from your check_kvm script. If that's consistent, then the issue is not with Nagios/NRPE but with your KVM install.

Comment: Hi Itai - join this chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11147/troubleshooting-nagios-nrpe-issue

Comment: It seems like i missed you at the chat, but i've updated the questions, thank you.

Comment: Try turning on debug in NRPE (might need a restart) and capture the output from wherever it logs to.

Comment: Have you tried running `virsh list --all` as _root_ and as _nagios_ on that system?

Comment: debug is already running on the `nrpe.cfg` file.
I've set nagios user to `/sbin/nologon` as it is configured on the rest of the vm host servers in my network.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a problem on a Gentoo server that resembles to yours at http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-806014-start-0.html

there is a nice method there to debug the issue.

the user on that post had a problem with check_disk and got the exact same error message as yours.

he was told to execute the following command:

```
ssh remote_ip /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 10 -c 5 -p "/"  2>&1
```

the `2>&1` will output stderr and might reveal the exact error.

so in your case replace remote_ip with the ip address of the server can't execute check_nrpe on. and replace the check_disk command with the full command that check_kvm is supposed to execute. if you run it without any parameters so you can just go and execute

```
  ssh <remote_ip> /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kvm 2>&1
```

that hopefully will reveal information regarding the problem.

good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, i get the same outputs:
`[root@Nagios-SRV ~]# ssh 1.1.1.159 /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_kvm "/"  2>&1root@1.1.1.159's password: 
hosts:3 OK:3 WARN:0 CRIT:0 - ab2c7:running alpweb5:running istaweb5:running
[root@Nagios-SRV ~]# ssh 1.1.1.159 /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H localhost "/"  2>&1
root@1.1.1.159's password: 
NRPE v2.14
[root@Nagios-SRV ~]# ssh 1.1.1.159 /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_kvm "/"  2>&1
root@1.1.1.159's password: 
Unknown guests
[root@Nagios-SRV ~]# `

Comment: have you tried running other scripts like check_disk ? does this behaviour happens on every script or just this one ?

Comment: Yes everything else works and so does the `check_kvm` script while checking other remote machines.

Comment: Mine says "sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo" :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I manage to solve it by killing the nagios process (on the monitored machine):

```
ps -ef | grep nagios
kill -9 [NagiosProcessNumber]
/etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server start
```

All went fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if selinux was turned on on the remote server(where the nrpe agent is running).

`[root@dl1-ap-ldap1 plugins]# getenforce 
Enforcing`

If yes, then turn it off, or configure 

`[root@dl1-ap-ldap1 plugins]# setenforce  0`

Answer (score -1):

Try commenting the following line in /etc/sudoers file:

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

After modification, it should be like this:

```
#Defaults    requiretty
```